# Is there any event which triggers generating ANDROID_ID?

Tags: android

I want to use ANDROID_ID(i.e., Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID) as my unique identifier.
In Android's doc, it says

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.

But I want to know

1. ANDROID_ID is first generated when the first boot completed(i.e., when BOOT_COMPLETED event fires) or
2. ANDROID_ID is generated before the boot completed (i.e., **before** BOOT_COMPLETED event fires)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be generated *before* the first boot completes, after the device has been reset, presumably before any app is ever able to access the value for the first time. A lot goes on during the first device boot to set up the device.